# Backbone and pusher - what data to send?

Tags: javascript, laravel, backbone.js, real-time, pusher

I am working a on backbone application at the moment, that "talks" to an API. A user can edit an organisation for example, the PATCH request will go to the API and get saved to the database, on a successful the API then "talks" to Pusher via this line,

`Pusherer::trigger('organisation_'.$id, 'organisation:change', json_encode(array('organisation' => $organisation)));`

Basically this telling pusher to trigger an event on the organisation_21 channel, the event that has happended is the organisation:change one, and the data to send is the organisation model.

What happens then on the Backbone side is that that i bind a method on to that channel and when the event happens that method will run, and update the view for the subscribed user.

HOWEVER, the data for my organisations has gotten quite big, the JSON object is 11.8kb, pusher won't process anything more than 10kb, is there a better way to work with backbone, my api and pusher other than sending the entire model?

On suggestion I like the idea, of doing the save, and fetching the model for new data in realtime via pusher. Would that look something like this?

```
organisationChanged:function(){
    var self = this;

    this.model.get('organisations').fetch({ //send GET To /api/organisation/id
      success: function(model, response) {
        self.model.get('organisations').set(response);
      }
    });
}
```

Fetch the model and set the attributes returned from the server to those of the model - so far this sounds correct to me yes? The complication comes that the model also contains a couple of collections, will set work on these, or is there a better way?

Comment: if user edit one field on organization. does other field get affected? backbone model save method can automatically set its value to the returned json of the request. can you skip the pusher and just return a json?

Comment: The pusher is for all other users, realtime communication

Comment: if you have control of the function bind to the channel then you can be so flexible. you can push a small json witb id. then you can rerun fetch on client side. or you push a zip binary data and unzip on client side. or even push the modified fields

Comment: @Evilsanta please see my edit, I am going to with saving, then running a fetch triggered by pusher to update the model, is my logic correct in my edit?

Answer (score 0):

The edit is the right idea, but with a little changes. 
The fetch would automatically change the model. From your code, it looks like your model is a bigger model, and organization is just a sub model. If this is the case:

```
var organizationmodel=this.model.get('organisations') // This would get the organization model. 
organizationmodel.fetch({ //send GET To /api/organisation/id
  success: function(model, response) { 
    // the model, and the organizationmodel both actually should point to the same object
    // and they are already changed based on the server returned stuff. so no need to do a set. 
    // if they are not, you can just set it again. 
    self.model.set('organizations',model);
  }
});
```